# Convolution filters (ie. "running average") with Laravel's collections, functionally

Tags: php, laravel, collections, functional-programming, convolution

what would be a good way to implement a 1D convolution filter over laravel's collections? meaning, take one iterated element, N neighbor elements and do a weighted average, weights defined in a a convolution matrix

it's not hard to imagine how to do it iteratively via a `for` loop, making use of an index

but is there a cleaner way, using collection's funcitonal approach via map/filter/something like that? i seem to have trouble accessing other element than the current iterated one

Answer (score 0):

I would look at Laravel's built-in collection methods to iterate over your collection (for loop way). https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#method-each I don't think there are any *matrix like* operations to create a 1D filter.

Comment: that's the thing. each iterates and only accessess currently iterated element

Comment: You could use a couple of chained functions `slice($index, $windowLength)->sum() / $windowLength` within a map or transform function on the original collection. Obviously you will have to allow for padding with zeros at the start etc. Other than this I can't think of a laravel-ish way of doing it

Comment: thank you for your suggestion. it's a good idea, but that's almost like using just an iteration :/ i thought there would be some map that would be aware of its neighbors or something like that. i will just use iteration i guess